# Automatically infer type in interface

Tags: typescript

I have a code like this

```
interface Model<T extends Type> {
  type: T
  get?: (value: ToNodeType<T>) => any
}
```

I hope it can automatically infer the parameter type of 'get' from the 'type' attribute

```
const model: Model = {
  type: 'int',
  get: (v) => 0
}
```

But it actually throws an error
`Generic type 'Model ' requires 1 type argument(s).`

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Model<T extends Type> {
  type: T
  get?: (value: ToNodeType<T>) => any
}

function defineModel<T extends Type>(model: Model<T>): Model<T> {
  return model;
}

const model = defineModel({
  type: 'int',
  get: (v) => 0
})

model;
// ^? const model: Model<'int'>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: I know this is a solution, but it will make the code look very bloated. If I need to define multiple models and put them into objects at the same time, the code will look like this
```
new Table({
  a: defineModel({
    type: 'int',
    get: (v) => 0
  }),
  b: defineModel({
    type: 'varchar',
    get: (v) => ''
  }),
  // ....
})